# Dismiss Snackbar On left swipe

Tags: android, onclick, android-snackbar

Simple code below for showing the Snackbar.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
       Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
               .setAction("Action", null).show();
}
```

This code correctly shows the Snackbar, when `onClick` event occurs.

Also, this snackbar can be dismissed by a swipe gesture.

But by default, only **Right-swipe** is dismissing the Snackbar. And I am unable to dismiss it with left-swipe.

How to dismiss snackbar on **left-swipe**?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JakubHolovsky No. As you can see, there is no Answer posted below this post. And it's almost 6-month old...so I am assuming this as a platform limitation at this point in time.

Comment: **Snackbar** needs a **CoordinatorLayout** as its root layout or some where on top of it, to perform its various operations like **swipe to dismiss**. You can find a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823767/snackbar-is-not-dismissing-on-swipe)

Comment: @AADTechnical hi you want to just dismiss that on swipe left or same animation like right swipe?

Comment: @Charuka dismissing on left swipe itself is fine too...

Comment: please re-read the question once. i guess i made it very clear what i want

Comment: @AADTechnical  In any case my answer address your topic **It dismisses snack Bar on left swipe** ! That's what i did. If that's what you want check my answer it works :))

Comment: @Charuka ok, i will try your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will dismiss `snackBar` on Left swipes (but without that animation on swipe  left)

- use `getView()` and take the `snackBar` layout
- use `setOnTouchListener`
- detect the movement and perform your action

and its Done!

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private float x1,x2;
            static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);

                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, "Helloo", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
                layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch(event.getAction())
                        {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                    x1 = event.getX();
                                    break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                    x2 = event.getX();
                                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                                    {// Left to Right swipe action
                                        if (x2 > x1)
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Left to Right swipe ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                                        }
                                        // Right to left swipe action
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Right to Left swipe ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                                            snackbar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Tap or Else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

another simple and cleaner approach could be the following:

```kotlin
val behavior = BaseTransientBottomBar.Behavior().apply {
    setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_ANY)
}
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    .setBehavior(behavior)
    .show()
```

with this you don't need to check and cast the layout params nor to use the `onShown` callback.

Answer (score 5):

hope this will help :

OnSwipeTouchListener.java:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

how to use : On MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    private Snackbar snackbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout); 

        snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("RETRY", null);

        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        snackbar.show();

        textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this)
        {
            public void onSwipeTop() {

            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {

            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD and SWIPE_THRESHOLD?

Comment: @SubanDhyako its for the gesture threshold, so that the snake bar not directly close if its touched only

Answer (score 3):

In the comments someone suggested the usage of `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`, this is the right approach. Handling the touch event on your own, is almost good idea, but no the right approach, because it will "break" the internal implementation of Snackbar and its Manager.

You need to replace default `SwipeToDismissBehavior` of the `Snackbar` just after you calll show() method.

```
     Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
           .setAction("Action", null).show();
    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = snackBarView.getLayoutParams();
    if (lp instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
        final CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) lp;
        final SwipeDismissBehavior<Snackbar.SnackbarLayout> behavior = new SwipeDismissBehavior<Snackbar.SnackbarLayout>();
        behavior.setStartAlphaSwipeDistance(0.1f);
        behavior.setEndAlphaSwipeDistance(0.6f);
        behavior.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_END_TO_START);
        behavior.setListener(new SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(View view) {
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDragStateChanged(int state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case SwipeDismissBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                    case SwipeDismissBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        snackbar.show();
                        break;
                    case SwipeDismissBehavior.STATE_IDLE:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        layoutParams.setBehavior(behavior);
    }
```

Or shorter approach:

```
    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = snackBarView.getLayoutParams();
    if (lp instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
        final CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) lp;
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
        if(behavior instanceof SwipeDismissBehavior){
            ((SwipeDismissBehavior) behavior).setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_END_TO_START); // or SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_ANY
        }
        layoutParams.setBehavior(behavior);
    }
```

Comment: Your shorter approach seems by far the best option of all the answers presented.

Comment: On caveat to the shorter approach. The snippet of code needs to be run in the `onShown(Snackbar)` callback. If run before then, the `getBehavior()` will return null.

Comment: works. best and clean approach together w the comment in `onShown` by @Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
snackbar.getBehavior().setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_ANY);
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to offer an explanation? How does this differ from the existing answers, and why do you prefer this approach? Are there cases it’s better suited to?