# Snackbar is not dismissing on swipe

Tags: android, android-snackbar

i have a snackbar in my appcompat activity. It has a button OK which dismiss the snackbar.It is working perfact. but i can't dismiss the snackbar on swipe(left to right).

Following is my code for snackbar....

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(view, "Error Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                        snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                            snackbar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                        snackbar.show();
```

**Edit 1**

I have Relative layout as parent layout in my activity's XML layout.

Comment: I ran into this error when putting a snack bar at the bottom of a dialog. Already using a `CoordinatorLayout`. No idea how to get it working.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Snackbar needs a CoordinatorLayout as its root layout or some where on top of it, to perform its various operations like swipe to dismiss. You need to have that some where in your layout hierarchy.

Further the view that we pass in the Snackbar.make() method is used to search a CoordinatorLayout some where in the view hierarchy. The method traverse from this view to the root view to find a CoordinatorLayout over which it can show the snackbar and perform its animations and operations.

So try replacing root layout to CoordinatorLayout and your problem will be solved.

Comment: is there any way to implement this behavior  with linear layout or any other layout???

Answer (score 6):

As a reference to **Ashwani Kumar**s answer.
I saw **Intimate** asked if there is a way to implement this with LinearLayout. Well simple wrap your original LinearLayout with a CoordinatorLayout with 
`match_parent` in `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` attributes.

this will keep your original arrangement and still make sure the Snackbar is swipable.

Snackbar will now look like this:

For fragments -

```
Snackbar.make(getView(), "Error Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
```

For activities -

```
Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Error Message",  Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
```

Assuming you wraped your whole layout with CoordinatorLayout and this is the root layout.

Answer (score 5):

I've written a library that supports swipe to dimiss behaviour even without providing CoordinatorLayout. Users can swipe both left or right to dismiss it (you can only swipe to right originally). It also includes progressBar and other stuff. Try it out https://github.com/tingyik90/snackprogressbar.

All you need to do is to create a SnackProgressBar and allow swipe to dismiss. Sample code:

```
SnackProgressBar messageType = new SnackProgressBar(
        SnackProgressBar.TYPE_MESSAGE, "Your message")
        .setSwipeToDismiss(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Snackbars in my GLSurfaceView game don't dismiss with a swipe, and users may not know to swipe anyway if they did. The following one line of code dismisses a Snackbar with any touch of the bar. Critically I found if the user does happen to hit the action button if it has one, whatever action it is set to do is still performed. The overall dismiss does not get in the way.

```
snackbar.getView().setOnClickListener(view -> snackbar.dismiss());
```